# Visual Studio : When and why a class file name change will automatically update references to that class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Sometimes when I'm using Visual Studio and I alter the name of the file containing a code element (i.e. a class, interface) I get a very helpful prompt that offers to automatically update all references/uses of that code element to the new file name.

And other times I don't.

In all cases I'm referring to when the code element file name matches the code elements type name.

Why does this sometimes occur and sometimes not?

I gather it has something to do with either a predefined link or VS's ability to real time resolve dependencies.

I have played around with this however and while in all cases VS can helpfully find all dependencies/uses of/to a code element using the context menu options, it doesn't always offer the prompt if I change the file name. So whats the secret?

[image: Helpful option]

Comment: I would be curious to know this too. In my experience, VS only produces the prompt when renaming Forms, however (as you say) the behaviour is inconsistent and only occurs some of the time...

Comment: It is inconsistent. I do find the feature gets (sometimes) activated  by all reference types (interfaces, classes, etc). I haven't seen it with value types tho. 

I guess the flip side is that it's nice to finally have some time to sweat the small stuff ;)

Answer (score 0):

It works this way (at least from my experience):

the refactor is activated only when the file contains exactly one single class with the same file as the file. I.e. it doesn't work if there are more classes in the file, or even when there is an enum, or a struct.

Comment: Yes I agree with all of what you  have written, but even when a class meets all of those conditions, 1/3 of the time it still doesn't re-factor. Im betting it's something at the project level rather than at the class level (beyond what you have stated here). i.e. it's what you've identified AND something else. I have not been able to deduce the pattern however.